# Create a Map with an Integer Key

Tags: dictionary, elixir

I want to create a map with a key of type integer, but this doesn't work:

```
iex(1)> a = %{3: "fdsfd"}
** (SyntaxError) iex:1: unexpected token: ":" (column 8, codepoint U+003A)

iex(1)> a = %{:3 => "fdsfd"}
** (SyntaxError) iex:1: unexpected token: ":" (column 7, codepoint U+003A)
```

Answer (score 8):

To use an Integer as a key, simply use it like this:

```
map = %{ 3 => "value" }
```

---

`:3` is an invalid value in Elixir; atoms are neither Strings or Integers in Elixir, they are constants where their name is their value. To use a key with only `3` as an atom, you would have to use this:

```
map = %{ :"3" => "value" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short-hand syntax for using an `integer` `atom` as a `Map` key:

```
map = %{ "3": "value" }
```

Try it:

```
iex(1)> map = %{ "1": 420 }
%{"1": 420}

iex(2)> keys = Map.keys(map)
[:"1"]

iex(3)> List.first(keys) |> i
Term
  :"1"
Data type
  Atom
```