# Convert Integer to Atom in Elixir

Tags: elixir

In Erlang, one can write `'1'` to get an integer-named atom. Elixir uses the syntax `:<name>` to define an atom, but `:1` is not possible:

```
iex(1)> :1
** (SyntaxError) iex:1: unexpected token: ":" (column 1, codepoint U+003A)
```

Is there a way in Elixir to generate an integer-named atom?

Comment: Related: [Map with Integer Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220630/create-a-map-with-an-integer-key/43220736#43220736)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the `1` in quotes and prepend `:` to get the equivalent of `'1'` in Erlang:

```
iex(1)> :"1"
:"1"
iex(2)> :'1'
:"1"
```

Answer (score 5):

Answer provided by Dogbert is the simplest one. If you would like to use functions for that unfortunately there's no function for that.
You can do it via converting int first to the Sting and then to the Atom.

```
1
|> Integer.to_string()
|> String.to_atom()
# :"1"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also leverage string interpolation:
`String.to_atom("#{your_number}")`